# Ошибка в запросе SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT * FROM matches m 
WHERE datetime >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND 
      datetime <= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND 
      status <> 2 
JOIN tournaments t ON m.tournament=t.name 
ORDER BY datetime ASC
```

Мой запрос, ругается на JOIN, без JOIN все работает. Как собственно получить колонку из другой таблицы в этом запросе? ))

Comment: `JOIN` должен идти до `WHERE`. Ну и добавить ее - колонку - в `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM matches AS m 
INNER JOIN tournaments AS t
  ON m.tournament = t.name 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY datatime ASC
```